# Compare two variables in an SQL WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near '@PacketCode'.

when I try to execute. Something is wrong with my WHILE loop but I can't see what. Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @PacketCode as varchar(255)
SET @PacketCode = 'ZZZ_Archive_TEST'

DECLARE @Value as varchar(255)
SET @Value = ''

DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 1

SELECT 
    @Value = (SELECT packetcode
              FROM tblScriptReports
              WHERE packetcode = @PacketCode)

WHILE (@PacketCode = @Value) 
BEGIN
    @PacketCode = @PacketCode + ' (' + @i + ')'

    SELECT @Value = (SELECT packetcode
                    FROM tblScriptReports
                    WHERE packetcode = @PacketCode)

    SET @i = @i + 1                   
END

SELECT @PacketCode
```

Comment: Is it Mysql or SQL-Server ? please tag it accordingly

Comment: It is SQL Server

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked documentation? Commented out lines until the error goes away and you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a SET in front of the @PacketCode in the BEGIN:

```
DECLARE @PacketCode as varchar(255)
set @PacketCode = 'ZZZ_Archive_TEST'

DECLARE @Value as varchar(255)
set @Value = ''

DECLARE @i int
set @i = 1

SELECT @Value = (SELECT packetcode
             FROM tblScriptReports
             WHERE packetcode = @PacketCode)

WHILE (@PacketCode = @Value) 

BEGIN

SET @PacketCode = @PacketCode + ' (' + @i + ')'

    SELECT @Value = (SELECT packetcode
                    FROM tblScriptReports
                    WHERE packetcode = @PacketCode)

    set @i = @i + 1                   
END

select @PacketCode
```

Answer (score 4):

In TSQL you assign variable values with the SET command.

So instead of this:

```
@PacketCode = @PacketCode + ' (' + @i + ')'
```

You must do this:

```
SET @PacketCode = @PacketCode + ' (' + @i + ')'
```

Funny that you did this correctly everywhere else in the code.

Comment: Yes this fixed it! Can't believe I missed it.